# Add a field with a dynamically mapped value to all documents

Tags: elasticsearch

There is an index `shakespeare` with the documents looking like following:

```
{
        "_index" : "shakespeare",
        "_type" : "line",
        "_id" : "24",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "play_name" : "Henry IV",
          "speech_number" : 1,
          "line_number" : "1.1.22",
          "text_entry" : "Forthwith a power of English shall we levy;",
          "speaker" : "KING HENRY IV",
          "line_id" : 1
        }
      },
```

I have a file/table/etc., which looks like following

```
+---------+--------------+
| line_id | is_a_good_line |
+---------+--------------+
|       1 |            1 |
|       2 |            1 |
|       3 |            0 |
|       4 |            0 |
|       5 |            1 |
+---------+--------------+
```

I want for each document in the `shakespeare` index have a new field `is_a_good_line` with a value matching the mapping from the table (based on the `line_id`). So, for the above example the value of `is_a_good_line` should be 1 like below:

```
{
        "_index" : "shakespeare",
        "_type" : "line",
        "_id" : "24",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "play_name" : "Henry IV",
          "speech_number" : 1,
          "line_number" : "1.1.22",
          "text_entry" : "Forthwith a power of English shall we levy;",
          "speaker" : "KING HENRY IV",
          "is_a_good_line" : 1,
          "line_id" : 1
        }
      },
```

I found a way to simply add a new field to all documents with a static value:

```
POST shakespeare/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.is_a_good_line = 0",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

How do I add a new field with a value defined by the mapping table above (based on the `line_id` value)?

Answer (score 1):

There are several options, from writing a simple program that parses the file/table and updates the relevant documents accordingly, to defining a Logstash pipeline that does the same job by using the appropriate input/output plugins. For sure, you cannot rely on Elasticsearch only to parse an external file.

If you want to go for the program option, it can be something as easy as a bash script that parses the file and curls `_update_by_query` with a query like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": { "line_id": <the_line_id_fetched_from_the_file>
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.is_a_good_line = <the_is_a_good_line_value_from_the_file>",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

or you can develop the same program in your favourite language using one of the many official elasticsearch client libraries: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/index.html

If instead you want to go for the Logstash pipeline option, you may want to have a look to the [file input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html) and [elasticsearch output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html) (check out the `script` option in particular), and maybe to the [csv filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html) (depending on the way the data is structured in your file/table).

Comment: Thank you for your input! From your experience, if I were to go the Logstash route, would it be efficient to try enriching *each* event with the data from this lookup table. Given that the lookup table has tens of millions of rows?

Comment: the good thing of Logstash is that is optimised for this kind of operations, and you can very easily parallelise the process or assign more resources to it. Also, as far as I understood your problem, is going to be a one-time job, then, I wouldn't wonder toooo much about efficiency